# How to analysis the code with pybossa vagrant

Tags: vagrant, pybossa

Analysis of data that belongs to GitHub. I need analysis. can anyone give me a suggestion? I have installed the required library to run it.

Comment: What library did you installed? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have to Install the required libraries for PYBOSSA. compilers and dev libraries to work. I have installed these packages:


sudo apt-get install python-dev build-essential libjpeg-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install dbus libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev                                                              (Ubuntu -os)